# Enable standby mode / deep sleep on SSD macs with mounted SD-card

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, sd-card

This question arose from the comments page of The Nifty Minidrive's [Kickstarter page](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1342319572/the-nifty-minidrive)

The Nifty Minidrive is essentially a microSD card adapter that fits perfectly into the SD-slot of the MacBook Pro / Pro Retina / Air so that a microSD card can be used as additional storage.

However a backer came across this [apple support document](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT4392) which explains that for a Mac to be able to enter Standby mode one criterium is that it must "Have no SD card inserted".

This is a potential deal breaker for many backers.

Is there a way to enable deep sleep mode even though an SD card is inserted?

(I have no way of actually testing this, but does an inserted SD card which isn't mounted prevent deep sleep as well? If it doesn't it should be possible to make a script that unmounts the SD card before the Mac goes to sleep and mounts it when it awakens?)

Answer (score 4):

SleepWatcher works fine with Mountain Lion. I've written an extensive guide to address the exact problem to [unmount and auto re-mount of SD Cards and any external HDDs using sleepwatcher](http://www.atpeaz.com/index.php/2012/automaticlly-eject-external-disks-on-sleep-reconnect-after-os-x/).

Answer (score 1):

If someone could confirm that unmounted (but still inserted) SD cards do not prevent standby mode / deep sleep I have a couple of proposed solutions to unmounting SD cards on sleep and mounting on wake:

ControlPane App - http://www.controlplaneapp.com/ - Can run "actions" on wake and sleep. Running a simple applescript to mount / unmount would do the trick (ML-compatibility in latest beta)

SleepWatcher - http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/ - Seems to be the more popular solution to do the same things as ControlPane App, no word on Mountain Lion compatibility though.

Scenario - http://www.lagentesoft.com/scenario/index.html - Paid alternative ($4.99)

Answer (score 0):

[Mountain](http://getmountainapp.com/) provides an automated solution for your problem.

In addition to the battery drain it occasionally happens that the MiniDrive is ejected when the Mac goes into deep sleep. This problem can also be solved with Mountain using the "Remount USB storages" command.

[This blog article](http://blog.appgineers.de/post/101608761084/new-advanced-feature-for-nifty-minidrive-users) explains you how to use [Mountain](http://getmountainapp.com/) to solve common issues with the Nifty MiniDrive like battery drain in sleep mode or the need to reattach the MiniDrive after waking up from sleep.